# How to print specific list in python from a large collection of list?

Tags: python-3.x

```
['90', '80', '70', '60', '50', '40', '30', '20', '10']
['09', '08', '07', '06', '05', '04', '03', '02', '01']
['11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19']
['29', '28', '27', '26', '25', '24', '23', '22', '21']
['31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39']
['49', '48', '47', '46', '45', '44', '43', '42', '41']
['51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59']
['69', '68', '67', '66', '65', '64', '63', '62', '61']
['71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79']
```

1. How to print the first list only? And
2. How to print the second and fifth lists only?

Comment: Do you know how to index a list?

Comment: Yeah, I know that. For example, a = ['90', '80', '70', '60', '50', '40', '30', '20']. If I want to access 80 from the list, I access it by writing a[1] because of index of 80 (its on 1st index). Also know about slicing. But confused about accessing the list, like how to access the first five lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lists = [['90', '80', '70', '60', '50', '40', '30', '20', '10'],

['09', '08', '07', '06', '05', '04', '03', '02', '01'],

['11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19'],

['29', '28', '27', '26', '25', '24', '23', '22', '21'],

['31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39'],

['49', '48', '47', '46', '45', '44', '43', '42', '41'],

['51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59'],

['69', '68', '67', '66', '65', '64', '63', '62', '61'],

['71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79']]
```

```
print(lists[0], "\n", lists[8])
```

It prints the first i.e [0] and the last i.e [8]

```
print(lists[0], "\n", lists[1], "\n", lists[4])
```

And this one answers your question 1st, 2nd, 5th

Comment: What if we've not list of lists, instead of we are dealing with separate 1000 lists, i mean not linked in a lists?

Comment: I just posted another answer according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If what you have is a list of lists, you access the inner lists in exactly the same way you access *any* element in a list.

Let's say you have a variable `x`:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

The first *list* in that variable is `x[0]`, `[1, 2, 3]`.

The first and third lists can be gotten (into another list of lists) with `[x[0], x[2]]`.

By way of comparison, getting the second item from the third list in that original list of lists (the `7`) can be done with `x[2][1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# somefile.txt
['90', '80', '70', '60', '50', '40', '30', '20', '10']
['09', '08', '07', '06', '05', '04', '03', '02', '01']
['11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19']
['29', '28', '27', '26', '25', '24', '23', '22', '21']
['31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39']
['49', '48', '47', '46', '45', '44', '43', '42', '41']
['51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59']
['69', '68', '67', '66', '65', '64', '63', '62', '61']
['71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '71']
```

```
# main.py
list = []

with open('somefile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        list.append(line)
```

```
print("first: ", list[0], "\n", "second: ", list[1], "\n", "third: ", list[4])
```

To print 1st list, 2nd list and 5th list

Comment: If satisfied you can choose this answer as best.